# Ender 3 Pro has too much space between extruder and bed

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling

I just finished assembling my Ender 3 Pro and am having trouble with bed leveling. The extruder doesn't even come close to the bed, the z-limit stops the nozzle about 3-4 mm away.

[image: Extruder and bed gap]

The leveling springs are already pretty uncompressed. Is there any way to decrease the gap? Should I be checking for a specific assembly step to see if I assembled it incorrectly somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried to lower the Z-endstop?

Comment: @kosteklvp In this case those questions do not apply, you need to have the nozzle to touch the paper to level the bed first. If the Z stop is pressed you cannot go past it without breaking the printer. In this case the Z-end stop needs to be lowered. You see that the end stop switch is pressed at the left of the photo.

Comment: @0scar I totally missed it. You are right, it can't go now any lower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only one thing you can do **if there are no more threads left on the levelling screws**, you need to move the Z-end stop assembly (depicted in the front left of your photo) to a lower position. Just unscrew the two hex screws a little and move the assembly down (blue arrow direction in the bottom/last image below). However, the more recent Ender 3 versions have a notch on the Z-end stop bracket:

[image]

That notch rests on the frame:

[image]

You should not be lowering this notch lower than the aluminum frame top.

Referring to your image and enlarging it, it appears you still have some threads left (encircled in red), this may be enough to get the bed to the nozzle (note that the leveling screw contains a knurled brass M3 insert, so you should be able to unscrew a little further):

[image]

If not, you should first unscrew the levelling screws a little so that you can properly tram the bed (alternatively, use longer countersunk screws). A detailed description can be found at [All3DP's Ender 3 (Pro) Z Offset: How to Adjust It](https://all3dp.com/2/ender-3-pro-z-offset/).

[image]

Comment: I  went ahead and moved the z-stop as you indicated. I've done a few test prints and things seems to be working fine. My only concern is that the piece indicated in this video https://youtu.be/ibsOYzXduYc?t=570 is now to the side of the frame instead of resting on it which just seems weird to me. Not sure if it will cause a problem or not but at least it works for now.

Comment: Please do check how your bed is mounted on the rail, because the notch should indicate the lowest point for the Z-stop, but good that you lowered it further. You now can print your own design or one from Thingiverse! It looks if your design needs a sheet of glass, than there wasn't a need to move it.

Answer (score 2):

It's normal for your nozzle to be some distance away from the bed. It should be adjusted properly at first. Since, you can't move your nozzle any lower, you should follow these steps:

1. **Lowering Z-endstop**

   You can manually reduce the distance between the nozzle and the bed by moving Z-endstop. Find the Z-axis limit switch (which is located on the left Z-axis on Ender-3) and loosen its screws. Next, set the switch a little lower to minimize Z-offset.
2. **Adjusting with bed leveling knobs**

   It looks like you still have some space between the bed level knob and the bed. You can lower this distance by turning the knob clockwise (looking from the top). You should turn all four knobs exactly the same amount. Do not turn the knobs more than one turn, lower the Z-endstop first. This option should be executed last to calibrate the offset as precisely as possible.

The nozzle shouldn't be touching the build plate, because it will damage the printing surface. To check if the distance is set correctly, you can print **[first layer test model](https://www.printables.com/pl/model/252059-perfect-first-layer-test)**. It may be necessary to level the bed at first.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your picture, I can tell that the leveling springs aren't standing straight up, rather they are leaning at an angle, making it so that full extension doesn't push the platform up as high as would be possible if they were straight. I had the exact same problem. I simply took a pen and nudged all the springs to make them stand up straight, and it solved the problem.

I know it doesn't look like it will help much, but trust me it does.